# Composición de funciones (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

¿ Por qué `group . sort  [3,4,5,3,3,5,4]` no se comporta como una composición de funciones cuyo argumento es igual a la lista ?

Por qué he de hacer: `group . sort $ [3,4,5,3,3,5,4]`   ?

entiendo el sentido de lo último, o sea, es equivalente a:

```
(group . sort) [3,4,5,3,3,5,4]
```

pero no sé por qué en el primer caso no lo es también.

Gracias.

Answer (score 4):

El operador de composición (de funciones) no es especial es Haskell, de hecho se define como un operador cualquiera, en *ghci*:

```
> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

con preferencia la más alta

```
> :i (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c   -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
infixr 9 .
```

de entre los operadores definidos en Haskell98

```
infixr 9  ., !!
infixr 8  ^, ^^, **
infixl 7  *, /, `quot`, `rem`, `div`, `mod`
infixl 6  +, -
infixr 5  :, ++
infix  4  ==, /=, <, <=, >=, >
infixr 3  &&
infixr 2  ||
infixl 1  >>, >>=
infixr 1  =<<
infixr 0  $, $!, `seq`
```

ésto quiere decir que cuando aplicas dicho operador, primero se evalúan las expresiones izquierda y derecha (bajo operadores de menor prioridad, claro) y luego se aplica.

En tu caso tenemos

```
group . sort [3,4,5,3,3,5,4]
```

la expresión izquierda no podemos reducirlo más, pero la expresión derecha sí y queda

```
group . [3,3,3,4,4,5,5]
```

si nos fijamos en el tipo del operador composición y el de las expresiones, que es

```
> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
> :t group
group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
> :t [3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5]
[3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5] :: Num t => [t]
```

el segundo argumento `[3,3,3,4,4,5,5]` que tiene tipo `*` es incorrecto, pues se espera el tipo `* -> *`, de forma informal:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) ->     (a -> b)      -> a -> c
          :               :
        group     [3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5]
          :               :
         Ok              Error
```

Como regla general, ten en cuenta que al componer funciones obtienes funciones, es decir

```
(group . sort)
```

es una función con tipo

```
group . sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

En particular, la composición de funciones es diferente a la aplicación de un argumento (parcial o total).

Ejemplo de aplicación parcial de un argumento, al ser parcial, obtenemos una función. Ésto es una función, porque `groupBy` pide dos argumentos y sólo aplicamos uno:

```
groupBy (==)
```

ésto ya no devuelve una función, devuelve un valor

```
groupBy (==) [3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5]
```

La aplicación parcial es precisamente lo que hace el operador `$`, pues tiene firma:

```
> :t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

Que como ves, el segundo argumento (tipo `*`) sí encaja con el de la lista (también tipo `*`).

Comment: Muchas gracias, todo es cuestión de la precedencia en las operaciones.